# Any travel site for medium/long distance multimodal comparison? (Train then plane etc.)

Tags: trains, online-resources, buses, routes, aircraft

I am trying to get from one minor city (X) in Europe to the other (Z). There are many options. I could train for an hour to X, then fly to Y, then train to Z. Or I could train from X to Z, or I could, bus to other airport W, fly to other airport Q, then train Q to Z, etc. etc.

Many website (e.g. skyscanner) will show me all the flights. Some show train sites will show me how to get from A to B via train (maybe by bus).

Is there any site that links them all together? So I enter a city/town name, and it tells me all the options for how to get there. Price is a factor, but not the main factor.

Comment: http://www.rome2rio.com/ comes to mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) is designed to do precisely this. It covers flights (even low-cost carriers), many trains and buses (both local transit and private long-distance buses), even some ferries and is able to combine them.

Icing on the cake is its ability to include some “driving” (taxi/private car) to get to the closest train station or airport as necessary, whereas train or flight search engines try to connect stations/airports and not cities in their vicinity. So you can actually enter the name of two small villages and let it do its magic.

As far as I can tell, it strives to include at least one bus-based and one train-based solution for any request, together with various flight options and associated transit to reach the airports.

One limitation is that because it covers so much, it's difficult to know exactly how comprehensive it is or how it chooses between various potential solutions. The design also emphasizes simplicity over customizability so compared to a typical flight search engine, you don't have many options.

Comment: Rome2Rio is definitely worth looking at, but should always be confirmed on other sites.  It doesn't list everything, doesn't always list the best, and sometimes lists things that don't exist.

Comment: Another flaw in Rome2Rio is if you want to select a country or region.  Instead of interpreting that as anything in that region, it translates it to one specific location in the region.  For example, say you want to go from England to anywhere in Europe.  No matter how good a route to Madrid is, Rome2Rio will not show it, because "Europe" really means Frankfort.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/) does this the best, although I don't often search this way - probably would have if the site existed when I lived in Europe...but I digress.

For example, if you want to go from [Paris, France to Trogir, Croatia](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris/Trogir), without even specifying dates (although you can for prices), it shows a train + plane option, a train + bus option, and a drive option.

Bear in mind no site could show you EVERY option. Even assuming you could collate the literally thousands of ways you could go around from A to B in Europe (especially if you take the 'long' way), it just wouldn't make sense to display it that way. However, this seems to take the most logical ways in the various forms of transport, and presents them pretty well.  As a result, it's the best I've seen.

(I have no affiliation with them)

Comment: Thanks, and yes I know it can't show *everything*. Just something more than "planes only"